# What is the advantage of using a pseudocode package instead of simply putting code inside of a verbatim block?

Tags: verbatim, sourcecode, pseudocode

What are the advantages of using a pseudocode package (like `algorithm2e`) above simply putting code inside of a `verbatim` block?

**Edit**:
In order to make the question less vague, I will say this: Sometimes, inside of a LaTeX document, a person will want to display code. The code to display might be pseudocode, Java, C, C++, Fortran, LaTeX, or be written in some other language. There are various goals. For example, indentation is a key feature of code. We wish to have indents preserved in the final output .pdf.  `\verbatim` preserves indentation, displays the result in a mono-spaced font, etc... Packages ***like*** `algorithm2e` (the specific package doesn't matter) can also be used to display code (***many*** kinds of code -- pseudocode, LaTeX code, Java...). The question is, what are the advantages of using a package tool to display your code instead of simply using the `\verbatim` command to display your code? `\verbatim` might be defined in some LaTeX package, but `\verbatim` is comes with LaTeX distributions more often than things like `algorithm2e` Often, no import statement is required for for using `\verbatim`. Does anything bad happen while using `\verbatim` which won't happen when using a tool like `algorithm2e`?

Comment: your question is rather vague, pseudocode is good for laying out pseudocode (typically with italic meta-variables and arrows and typeset math expressions) and verbatim is good for laying out real code, verbatim. So they take different input and produce different output, so the question of advantages of one over the other doesn't really arise so often.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you believe that `verbatim` is for "real-code" and that something like `algorithm2e` is better for "pseudo-code," then you could give that as an answer. You could say that The advantage of `verbatim` is that `verbatim` is better for displaying "real-code." Just because you think the answer to the question is obvious, that does not mean that the is vague.

Comment: No, I did not vote to close the question but I wouldn't answer it (and I wouldn't vote to open) it unless you edit it to be more specific. No answers can be posted anyway while it's on hold.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Many text editors don't distinguish between "**pseudo**-code" and "**real**-code." Also, human authors usually display both "**pseudo**-code" and "**real**-code" using very similar tools. For example, on stack overflow users choose to display their **pseudo**-code in a mono-spaced font. Stack overflow users also usually put **real**-code in a mono-spaced font. I would think that a tool good for displaying **pseudo**-code would also be good for  **real**-code. By "**real**-code," did you mean LaTeX code? Are you saying that `\verbatim` is good for displaying LaTeX code?

Answer (score 3):

The one ([`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), but also [`algorithms`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), ...) is meant to be used with *pseudocode* and therefore contains formatting options for statements. The latter (`verbatim`) is typically used to place *actual code* in the document as-is, without formatting.

The two can be combined when using [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`fancyvrb`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), for example.

What's the advantage? It depends on the application. Pseudocode works well to provide a generic description of an algorithm in an article. This also doesn't require an understanding of the language used, whereas `verbatim` requires an understanding of the language, or may require smaller pieces of code for a clear understanding.

Comment: Why would code inside of a `\verbatim` block need to be something which "requires an understanding of the language?" It is true that you must understand LaTeX in order to use`\verbatim`. However, I presume that you mean an understanding of the language is required to to read what is visible in the output document. You seem to be saying, put "**actual**" code, like Java, inside a `\verbatim` block, but use something like `listings`, or `fancyvrb` for **pseudo**-code. Why? `\verbatim` doesn't know whether you give it Java or pseudo-code. It's about making code readable in the output.

Comment: @IdleCustard: True. Since people typically post actual code within a `verbatim` environment (because languages each have their own syntax that might require the use of special characters like `%` or `$` or `&` or ...), in order to understand the actual code, you'll have to understand that language.

Comment: @IdleCustard the input to verbatim, listings, minted, fancyverb is typically a file in some language (perhaps annotated with tex) to be shown _verbatim_.  the input to packages like `algorith...` is essentially a stylized latex math mode,  with help for indenting to show program flow, so it is normally used for describing program logic/pseudo-code rather than displaying anything that could be used verbatim with a programming language compiler.